How to run interactive docker alpine image on windows
When I run this command:

docker run --name mycontainer -d -i -t alpine /bin/sh

I get this error

Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.


The -d option obviously prevents you from interacting with the container. Windows is crazy but maybe if you simply omit /bin/sh (assuming the image's ENTRYPOINT already does something similar by default).

This was fixed with: docker run --name mycontainer -it alpine

This was fixed.
docker run --name mycontainer -it alpine
